# Group by Multi Language Field

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to find the users who are based on local language and English. As my data field contains both English and Local language.

```
ID  FULL_NAME
1   Logan
2   โลแกน
3   ซาเวียร์
4   Xavier
```

Is there a way to group something as following using SQL ?

```
english 2
other-lang 2
```

My database is really huge (should be more than 6M). So might need a very optimal solution.

Open for both MySQL/Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
select 'English -' + convert(varchar(50),count(*)) from tablename where full_name like '[a-z]%'
union all
select 'Other Lang -' + convert(varchar(50), count(*) - (select count(*) from tablename where full_name like '[a-z]%')) from tablename
```